# How to retrieve data from a reference cursor - passed as an INOUT parameter- to a stored proc from a shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell

I have a stored proc which is called from a shell script. The parameters passed to the stored proc includes a reference cursor which is being passed as an INOUT parameter. I have to retrieve the data returned by the reference cursor after executing the stored proc. How do i access the data in the reference cursor?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The shell script is connecting to the database in order to run the stored procedure, right?  I'm guessing that it is using SQL*Plus to connect.  Assuming that the cursor variable is declared in SQL*Plus, you should be able to simple PRINT the cursor, i.e.

```
SQL> create procedure return_rc( p_rc in out sys_refcursor )
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    open p_rc
  5     for
  6     select * from emp;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> variable rc refcursor;
SQL> exec return_rc( :rc );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO   FAKE_COL        FOO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 smith      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800
        20          1

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300
        30          1

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500
        30          1


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO   FAKE_COL        FOO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975
        20          1

      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400
        30          1

      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850
        30          1


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO   FAKE_COL        FOO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450
        10          1

      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000
        20          1

      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000
        10          1


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO   FAKE_COL        FOO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0
        30          1

      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1110
        20          1

      7900 SM2        CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950
        30          1


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO   FAKE_COL        FOO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000
        20          1

      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300
        10          1


14 rows selected.
```

If you are trying to fetch the data in a PL/SQL block

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_rc     sys_refcursor;
  3    l_emprec emp%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    return_rc( l_rc );
  6    loop
  7      fetch l_rc into l_emprec;
  8      exit when l_rc%notfound;
  9      dbms_output.put_line( l_emprec.ename );
 10    end loop;
 11    close l_rc;
 12* end;
SQL> /
smith
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS
SM2
FORD
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks.Actually, i am trying to execute a procedure in PL SQL block.The code is like DECLARE cursor refcursor;BEGIN- procedure-Now i want to display the inout parameter ie the reference cursor inside the PLSQL block. But with the above code, i am not able to do that

Comment: Hi Justin..Thanks..But i have a doubt.In line no:3, emp is the table name and ename is a column in the table,rite? I am using a temporary table instead. I am getting error at line 7. It says "ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at line 7" What can be the issue?

Comment: Hi..I found the problem. The cursor was not returning all the columns from the table. How can i overcome this scenario? I am executing in toad. I am afraid that dbms_output.put_line willnot work in toad. How can i obtain the output?

Comment: Just like any cursor, you'd need to declare variables to fetch the data into.  Whatever columns the procedure is selecting would need to be declared in the PL/SQL block to be fetched into.  Toad should be able to display the output of a dbms_output.put_line.  If you want to do something else with the data, you'll need to be more specific.  You should be able to return a cursor to Toad.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to write code something like this:-

first create SP like this:-

```
create or replace PROCEDURE impact_type_test
(
  v_impact_type_id IN NUMBER,
  cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS

BEGIN

   OPEN  cv_1 FOR
      SELECT impact_type_id 
        FROM impact_type
       WHERE  impact_type_id = v_impact_type_id ;
END;
```

then in shell script call SP like this:-

```
sqlplus -S /nolog  <<-! >/dev/null 2>&1
connect ${ORACLE_UID}/${ORACLE_PWD}@${ORACLE_DB};
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set heading off
set verify off
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 150
spool ${WORKDIR}/ouput_data.dat

var vc refcursor;
execute impact_type_test (1,:vc);
print vc;

spool off;
exit
!

while read line
do 
echo $line
done <${WORKDIR}/ouput_data.dat
```

output would be something like this:-

```
113
```

---

if you want to read specific fields from SP output then see this code below:-

```
create or replace PROCEDURE impact_type_test
(
  v_impact_type_id IN NUMBER,
  cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS

BEGIN

   OPEN  cv_1 FOR
      SELECT impact_type_id as impact_type_id,IMPACT_TYPE_NM as IMPACT_TYPE_NM,SEVERITY_ORDER as SEVERITY_ORDER
        FROM impact_type
       WHERE  impact_type_id = v_impact_type_id ;
END;
```

then in shell script call SP like this:-

```
sqlplus -S /nolog  <<-! >/dev/null 2>&1
connect ${ORACLE_UID}/${ORACLE_PWD}@${ORACLE_DB};
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set heading off
set verify off
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 150
spool ${WORKDIR}/ouput_data.dat

var vc refcursor;
execute impact_type_test (1,:vc);
print vc;

spool off;
exit
!

while read -r impact_type_id IMPACT_TYPE_NM 
do 
echo $impact_type_id
echo $IMPACT_TYPE_NM

done <${WORKDIR}/ouput_data.dat
```

if you will see closely, SP is returning 3 fields(impact_type_id,SEVERITY_ORDER) Impact_type_nm, but in shell script I am reading only 2 fields (impact_type_id, Impact_type_nm).

output would be something like this:-

```
113
High
```